# Trying to access user's Facebook and Twitter simultaneously via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to sign in to both Facebook and Twitter through my site at the same time. The plan is to post to my site and have the site post to both at the same time. The code works for signing in to one or the other, but it doesn't work when signing into one and THEN the other. I'm using the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for Facebook and [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/) for Twitter.

```
$userId = $this->facebook->getUser(); 
            if($userId == 0){
                $this->data['fbloginurl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access'));
            } else {
                if($this->session->userdata('userInfo')->userType == 1 || $this->session->userdata('userInfo')->userType == 2){
                    $this->facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
                    $newdata = array('fbInfo'  => $this->facebook->api('/me/accounts')['data']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                    foreach($this->session->userdata('fbInfo') as $page){
                        if($page['category'] != 'Application'){
                            $this->status_model->updateToken($page['name'],$page['access_token']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth($this->config->item('tmhOAuth'));
            if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']) && $this->session->userdata('oauth') && !$this->session->userdata('access_token')){
                access_token($tmhOAuth);
            } else if(!$this->session->userdata('access_token')){
                $this->data['twloginurl'] = request_token($tmhOAuth);
            } else {
                $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $this->session->userdata('access_token')['oauth_token'];
                $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $this->session->userdata('access_token')['oauth_token_secret'];
                $newdata = array('twitInfo'  => getTwitInfo($tmhOAuth));
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            }
```

I can sign in to Facebook OR Twitter and it works fine, but doing both at the same time doesn't seem to work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make sure there are no variables holding value from the first part (Facebook) which is used in the second part which may result in an absolute failure. And same happens for the session variables. Its probably that which makes your script fail.